# How can I interpolate the following data and get the equation?

Tags: matlab, interpolation, data-analysis, regression-analysis

I want to interpolate between three vectors which have 8 rows in each. For eg. X = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8], Y = [7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 ], Z = [15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22]
I want to find the equation Z = f(x,y).Can interpolation be used here without neglecting any data or regression is the only option?
Because if I try to interpolate using quadratic polynomial there will be 6 variables and I have 8 equations. If I increase the degree to 3 number of variables will be more than 8.

Comment: Do you even want an interpolating polynomial? What is the purpose of doing this? Would you be happy with an equation $z=f(x,y)$ that matches the listed data but gives nonsensical results for other values of $x,y$?

Comment: At this point I am not concerned about the results. But is it possible to  do the interpolation(Not piecewise) with above data?

Comment: Bilinear interpolation, may be

Comment: Have a look at `griddata`. But it is still unclear to me whether you are interested in interpolated values or the interpolation formula.